# Find object by id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have this tree:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "parentId": null,
    "name": "Comapny",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1235,
            "parentId": 0,
            "name": "Experiences",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 3333,
                    "parentId": 154,
                    "name": "Lifestyle",
                    "children": [],
                    "merchants": [
                        {
                            "id": 348,
                            "name": "Experience Mad"

                        },
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "name": "Virgin Experience Days"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 319291392,
                    "parentId": 318767104,
                    "name": "Other Experiences",
                    "children": [],
                    "merchants": [
                        {
                            "id": 353,
                            "name": "Tasterlab"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 19,
                            "name": "Activity Superstore"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "merchants": [
                {
                    "id": 35715,
                    "name": "Red Letter Days"
                },
                {
                    "id": 85,
                    "name": "The Hut"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find object by id. For example if need to find an object with id:353, I have to get:

```
{"id": 353,"name": "Tasterlab"}
```

if I need to find an object with `id:1235`, I have to get: `{"id": 1235,"name": "Experiences"}`

I tried many times but given the complexity of the tree for me is hard to do what I want.

Comment: It's just a simple recursive function.

Comment: use loop inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findId(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id == id) {
        return obj;
    }
    if (obj.children) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            var found = findId(obj.children[i], id);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    if (obj.merchants) {
        for (i = 0; i < obj.merchants.length; i++) {
            found = findId(obj.merchants[i], id);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `"merchants"` array ;-)

Comment: thanks Barmar, but I'm getting "TypeError: obj.children is undefined"

Comment: If an object might not have children or merchanges, you need an `if` statement to test whether the properties exist first.

Answer (score 1):

Code is taken from: http://techslides.com/how-to-parse-and-search-json-in-javascript/

*Return an array of objects according to key, value, or key and value matching*

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));    
        } else 
        //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
        if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
            objects.push(obj);
        } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
            //only add if the object is not already in the array
            if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                objects.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

*Return an array of values that match on a certain key*

```
function getValues(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getValues(obj[i], key));
        } else if (i == key) {
            objects.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

*Return an array of keys that match on a certain value*

```
function getKeys(obj, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getKeys(obj[i], val));
        } else if (obj[i] == val) {
            objects.push(i);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```